# iPhone 7 wont switch to headphones?

Tags: iphone, headphones

When I plug headphones into my iPhone 7, the audio continues to play through the speakers. I have tried with 3 separate pairs. I couldn't find any troubleshooting tips, other than to check for debris. Any suggestions?

Comment: What headphones are you using with your iPhone 7? Apparently, iPhone 7 doesn't have a 3.5mm headphone jack. Are you using a Lightening to 3.5mm adaptor? Does plugging-in Lightening to USB cable working fine for charging and iTunes sync?

Comment: yes, the usb cable works for itunes/charging. I have tried with the apple earbuds which came with the phone, a pair of lightning ear buds from another manufacturer, and with ear buds plugged into a 3.5mm adapter.

Comment: Did any headphones ever work or is this a new issue?  Also, have you tried bluetooth headphones?  If so, did they work correctly?

Comment: New issue, worked fine for months of use prior to today. I dont have bluetooth headphones, but it worked fine with bluetooth for my car stereo.

Comment: I just noticed that phone audio only plays through the large speaker, it doesnt give an option to switch it to headset.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `large speaker`? What do you mean by `it doesn't give an option to switch it to headset`?

Comment: @NimeshNeema When on a phone call, audio only plays in speaker phone mode. When I click the audio option, it does not give any option other than `speaker`:  https://imgur.com/a/JM5WNfE